# Order column by numbers containing . and then alphabetically

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I want to order one of my tables column named `smsfilename` which contains values like this:

| id | smsfilename |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1.1.18 Termino |
| 2 | 2 abcc |
| 3 | 1.1.1 xyz |
| 4 | 1.1.5 ship |
| 5 | 1.1.11 abc |
| 6 | 1.1.11 aa |
| 7 | 1.2 aarun |
| 8 | 1.1 arun |
| 9 | 1.1.10 vesta |
| 10 | 1.1.1 TrojanWar |

I want to sort the values like this:

| id | smsfilename |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1.1 arun |
| 2 | 1.1.1 TrojanWar |
| 3 | 1.1.1 xyz |
| 4 | 1.1.5 ship |
| 5 | 1.1.10 vesta |
| 6 | 1.1.11 aa |
| 7 | 1.1.11 abc |
| 8 | 1.1.18 Termino |
| 9 | 1.2 aarun |
| 10 | 2 abcc |

I have used this mysql query, but it does not achieve my expected result

```
select * 
from smsproceduresfiles 
order by cast('/' + replace(smsFileName , '.', '/') + '/' as UNSIGNED) ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

If want to sort the values in `smsfilename` column first in numeric and then alphabetically; then you do it as below :

```
SELECT *
FROM smsproceduresfiles
ORDER BY 
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(smsFileName, ' ', 1) + 0,
  LPAD(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(smsFileName, ' ', 1), '.', -1), 10, '0'),
  smsFileName;
```

Here is a [working SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/30ed30/1)

You will be also able to do it using [`INET_ATON` function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-aton) in mysql as follows:

```
SELECT *
FROM smsproceduresfiles
ORDER BY 
  INET_ATON(
    CONCAT(
      SUBSTRING_INDEX(smsFileName, ' ', 1), 
      '.', 
      LPAD(
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(smsFileName, ' ', 1), '.', -1), 
        10, 
        '0'
      )
    )
  ),
  smsFileName;
```

Here is [a working Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/30ed30/2)

Now,
If you want to keep the id column also sorted (from 1 to 10) as in expected output; You can do it using `ROW_NUMBER()` in MYSQL 8.0.

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS id, smsfilename
FROM smsproceduresfiles
ORDER BY 
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(smsFileName, ' ', 1) + 0,
  LPAD(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(smsFileName, ' ', 1), '.', -1), 10, '0'),
  smsFileName;
```

Here is the [working DBFIDDLE](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mZyfxnW2wugK997RguDSdb/0)

This gets you the expected output as :

| id | smsfilename |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1.1 arun |
| 2 | 1.1.1 TrojanWar |
| 3 | 1.1.1 xyz |
| 4 | 1.1.5 ship |
| 5 | 1.1.10 vesta |
| 6 | 1.1.11 aa |
| 7 | 1.1.11 abc |
| 8 | 1.1.18 Termino |
| 9 | 1.2 aarun |
| 10 | 2 abcc |